# How to change Wordpress Media Strings with media_view_strings filter

Tags: wordpress

Hi I want to change some strings in media popup i found that i can filter $strings variable width  [media_view_strings](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/media_view_strings/) filter , how i can do this ?

i want to change

Here is the wp-includes/media.php file

```
$strings = array(
    // Generic
    'url'         => __( 'URL' ),
    'addMedia'    => __( 'Add Media' ),
    'search'      => __( 'Search' ),
    'select'      => __( 'Select' ),
    'cancel'      => __( 'Cancel' ),
    'update'      => __( 'Update' ),
    'replace'     => __( 'Replace' ),
    'remove'      => __( 'Remove' ),
    'back'        => __( 'Back' ),
    /* translators: This is a would-be plural string used in the media manager.
       If there is not a word you can use in your language to avoid issues with the
       lack of plural support here, turn it into "selected: %d" then translate it.
     */
    'selected'    => __( '%d selected' ),
    'dragInfo'    => __( 'Drag and drop to reorder media files.' ),

    // Upload
    'uploadFilesTitle'  => __( 'Upload Files' ),
    'uploadImagesTitle' => __( 'Upload Images' ),

    // Library
    'mediaLibraryTitle'      => __( 'Media Library' ),
    'insertMediaTitle'       => __( 'Insert Media' ),
    'createNewGallery'       => __( 'Create a new gallery' ),
    'createNewPlaylist'      => __( 'Create a new playlist' ),
    'createNewVideoPlaylist' => __( 'Create a new video playlist' ),
    'returnToLibrary'        => __( '&#8592; Return to library' ),
    'allMediaItems'          => __( 'All media items' ),
    'allDates'               => __( 'All dates' ),
    'noItemsFound'           => __( 'No items found.' ),
    'insertIntoPost'         => $hier ? __( 'Insert into page' ) : __( 'Insert into post' ),
    'unattached'             => __( 'Unattached' ),
    'trash'                  => _x( 'Trash', 'noun' ),
    'uploadedToThisPost'     => $hier ? __( 'Uploaded to this page' ) : __( 'Uploaded to this post' ),
    'warnDelete'             => __( "You are about to permanently delete this item.\n  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete." ),
    'warnBulkDelete'         => __( "You are about to permanently delete these items.\n  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete." ),
    'warnBulkTrash'          => __( "You are about to trash these items.\n  'Cancel' to stop, 'OK' to delete." ),
    'bulkSelect'             => __( 'Bulk Select' ),
    'cancelSelection'        => __( 'Cancel Selection' ),
    'trashSelected'          => __( 'Trash Selected' ),
    'untrashSelected'        => __( 'Untrash Selected' ),
    'deleteSelected'         => __( 'Delete Selected' ),
    'deletePermanently'      => __( 'Delete Permanently' ),
    'apply'                  => __( 'Apply' ),
    'filterByDate'           => __( 'Filter by date' ),
    'filterByType'           => __( 'Filter by type' ),
    'searchMediaLabel'       => __( 'Search Media' ),
    'noMedia'                => __( 'No media attachments found.' ),

    // Library Details
    'attachmentDetails'  => __( 'Attachment Details' ),

    // From URL
    'insertFromUrlTitle' => __( 'Insert from URL' ),

    // Featured Images
    'setFeaturedImageTitle' => $post_type_object->labels->featured_image,
    'setFeaturedImage'      => $post_type_object->labels->set_featured_image,

    // Gallery
    'createGalleryTitle' => __( 'Create Gallery' ),
    'editGalleryTitle'   => __( 'Edit Gallery' ),
    'cancelGalleryTitle' => __( '&#8592; Cancel Gallery' ),
    'insertGallery'      => __( 'Insert gallery' ),
    'updateGallery'      => __( 'Update gallery' ),
    'addToGallery'       => __( 'Add to gallery' ),
    'addToGalleryTitle'  => __( 'Add to Gallery' ),
    'reverseOrder'       => __( 'Reverse order' ),

    // Edit Image
    'imageDetailsTitle'     => __( 'Image Details' ),
    'imageReplaceTitle'     => __( 'Replace Image' ),
    'imageDetailsCancel'    => __( 'Cancel Edit' ),
    'editImage'             => __( 'Edit Image' ),

    // Crop Image
    'chooseImage' => __( 'Choose Image' ),
    'selectAndCrop' => __( 'Select and Crop' ),
    'skipCropping' => __( 'Skip Cropping' ),
    'cropImage' => __( 'Crop Image' ),
    'cropYourImage' => __( 'Crop your image' ),
    'cropping' => __( 'Cropping&hellip;' ),
    'suggestedDimensions' => __( 'Suggested image dimensions:' ),
    'cropError' => __( 'There has been an error cropping your image.' ),

    // Edit Audio
    'audioDetailsTitle'     => __( 'Audio Details' ),
    'audioReplaceTitle'     => __( 'Replace Audio' ),
    'audioAddSourceTitle'   => __( 'Add Audio Source' ),
    'audioDetailsCancel'    => __( 'Cancel Edit' ),

    // Edit Video
    'videoDetailsTitle'     => __( 'Video Details' ),
    'videoReplaceTitle'     => __( 'Replace Video' ),
    'videoAddSourceTitle'   => __( 'Add Video Source' ),
    'videoDetailsCancel'    => __( 'Cancel Edit' ),
    'videoSelectPosterImageTitle' => __( 'Select Poster Image' ),
    'videoAddTrackTitle'    => __( 'Add Subtitles' ),

    // Playlist
    'playlistDragInfo'    => __( 'Drag and drop to reorder tracks.' ),
    'createPlaylistTitle' => __( 'Create Audio Playlist' ),
    'editPlaylistTitle'   => __( 'Edit Audio Playlist' ),
    'cancelPlaylistTitle' => __( '&#8592; Cancel Audio Playlist' ),
    'insertPlaylist'      => __( 'Insert audio playlist' ),
    'updatePlaylist'      => __( 'Update audio playlist' ),
    'addToPlaylist'       => __( 'Add to audio playlist' ),
    'addToPlaylistTitle'  => __( 'Add to Audio Playlist' ),

    // Video Playlist
    'videoPlaylistDragInfo'    => __( 'Drag and drop to reorder videos.' ),
    'createVideoPlaylistTitle' => __( 'Create Video Playlist' ),
    'editVideoPlaylistTitle'   => __( 'Edit Video Playlist' ),
    'cancelVideoPlaylistTitle' => __( '&#8592; Cancel Video Playlist' ),
    'insertVideoPlaylist'      => __( 'Insert video playlist' ),
    'updateVideoPlaylist'      => __( 'Update video playlist' ),
    'addToVideoPlaylist'       => __( 'Add to video playlist' ),
    'addToVideoPlaylistTitle'  => __( 'Add to Video Playlist' ),
);

/**
 * Filter the media view settings.
 *
 * @since 3.5.0
 *
 * @param array   $settings List of media view settings.
 * @param WP_Post $post     Post object.
 */
$settings = apply_filters( 'media_view_settings', $settings, $post );

/**
 * Filter the media view strings.
 *
 * @since 3.5.0
 *
 * @param array   $strings List of media view strings.
 * @param WP_Post $post    Post object.
 */
$strings = apply_filters( 'media_view_strings', $strings,  $post );
```

that's all

Answer (score 1):

Try following code in your plug-in:

```
function wdm_custom_media_view_strings( $strings ) {

    /*
    1. Copy and paste array $strings from media.php
    2. Now here you can modify $strings as per requirement.
    */

    //Do not forget to return $strings
    return $strings;

}

add_filter('media_view_strings', 'wdm_custom_media_view_strings');
```

Feel free to ask doubts.